# Starting node.js, getting confusing results

Tags: node.js

I'm currently diving into node.js stuff starting with very simple examples.

The following code is not really a big deal but already confuses me:

```
require('http')
    .createServer( function( req, res ) {
        console.log( 'receiving request' );
        res.end( 'end' );
    } )
    .listen( 1337, "localhost" );
```

After having started the server via console I called http://localhost:1337
In the console I got the "receiving request"-message *two* times not one time as expected.

What is this all about? Did I already mess this easy thin up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers will automatically make a call to /favicon.ico when requesting a page. Your node server responds to both the "page" request and the "favicon.ico" request. Hence the two log lines.

Comment: Yeah, [here's a snippet](https://gist.github.com/763822) that will help you "hide" those requests. BTW, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark just to the left of the answer. Good Luck!

Comment: thank you! i was about to accept but had to wait 9 more minutes, i had to leave and was just returning right now.

Comment: Awesome, I forget the constraints on new members. Thank you!